# Cannot Decode RFID Tag

Tags: python, rfid, epc

Thanks for taking a look.

I'll include a full description here as I'm not sure what might be relevant to solving my question.

**Background Information:**

My current project involves reading [RFID (Radio Frequency ID) tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification). To achieve this I'm using a Rasberry Pi with the [Fonkan FM 503 RFID Reader](https://es.aliexpress.com/item/1005003838583428.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.0.0.288a6bbR6bbR4e&gps-id=pcDetailTopMoreOtherSeller&scm=1007.40000.327270.0&scm_id=1007.40000.327270.0&scm-url=1007.40000.327270.0&pvid=f6ac03ca-91d9-44db-a09b-47a6408182cc&_t=gps-id:pcDetailTopMoreOtherSeller,scm-url:1007.40000.327270.0,pvid:f6ac03ca-91d9-44db-a09b-47a6408182cc,tpp_buckets:668%232846%238114%231999&pdp_npi=4%40dis%21EUR%2190.90%2165.45%21%21%2194.67%21%21%40211b442116950359978126278e11b1%2112000027313711271%21rec%21ES%21851497238%21S). So far I got it to work using the code below and can correctly read and decode the test RFID that came with it. See the manufacturers instructions and my code below:

[image: rfid reader overview]

[image: rfid reader commands]

```
import serial
import time
from subprocess import Popen

ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate = 38400, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, timeout=1)

while 1:

  ser.write(b"\nU\r")
  epcs = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
  epcs = epcs.decode("ascii").replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "")
  time.sleep(1)
  if not epcs == "Q" and not epcs == "U" and not epcs == "":
    epcs = epcs.split("U")
    for epc in epcs:
        print(epc)
```

This renders the following tag value in hexadecimal:

```
3000E280699500005011153664F378DF
```

With this EPC I was able to go to the [GS1 decoder page](https://www.gs1.org/services/epc-encoderdecoder) and see that the tag decodes to get the information contained within.

[image: gs1 decoder working]

**The Question:**

Encouraged by this I decided to try and find some more tags to read so I went to [Zara Home](https://maps.app.goo.gl/ivEvfYoqp4U1aFMH8) a home furnishing store in Spain where RFID is used to track inventory and bought some bowls like the one below:

[image: zara home bowl]

These came with the following RFID tags stuck to them:

[image: rfids_top]

[image: rfid bottom]

When reading these with my code above, I get the following output EPC values:

```
400009CA3D5A706573802B1D46418C4004235E73 (Returns Total value is out of range)
440009CA2662748C77002CFDDABC286004239E2D (Returns Header 68 is not a known EPC header)
400009CA3D5A706573802B1D467D8C400423D9B6 (Returns Total value is out of range)
400009CA3D5A6D58338026D0DEF60F400423DC64 (Can be decoded)
```

The problem is that I can't decode these using the [GS1 decoder page](https://www.gs1.org/services/epc-encoderdecoder) or [pyepc](https://pypi.org/project/pyepc/) which is a decoding library. I also tried other online tools but being very new to this field couldn't really understand the documentation about different types of tags and the data within them.

[image]

I'd like to ask:

- Are these EPC codes and am I reading the tags correctly?
- How can I decode these EPC codes? (I'd like to get the company Id)